# Ant build fails on library project

Tags: android, ubuntu, ant

I have two projects, say A and B. B is a library project and which have project A on it's build path. Project B has been added as a library reference in Project A.

My problems are:

1. When I run 'ant clean debug install' from location of Project A , I'm getting errors on Project B (where project A is referred)
2. When I run 'ant build' from location of Project B, I'm getting the same errors mentioned above.

Here is some logs:

```
-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 677 source files to ProjectB/bin/classes
    [javac] ProjectB/src/com/x/y/z/abc.java:31: package (Project A package name) does not exist
```

Comment: please post your log cat error and also give some detail summary so that we can help you dear.

Comment: BUILD FAILED
/home/android6/Desktop/software/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/android6/Desktop/software/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/android6/Desktop/software/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @Ricky On compiling Project B, It showed errors like package(package name from project A) does not found.